# Cell content upload when choosing dropdown menu option Word/VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

So i got requested for:

a word file with a table in it where when picking an option in the drop down menu within a cell, another cell updates it's content.

i have the Drop down set up[here the drop down content control properties with names and values equalized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AYQM.png)

I have a plain text content control in the cell [not much to be added here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3erLf.png)

when i enter the code

```
Sub UpdateContent()
    Dim dropdown As ContentControl
    Dim cell As ContentControl
    
    Set dropdown = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("KörperTypen").Item(1)
    Set cell = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Klassifizierungen").Item(1)
    
    
    Select Case dropdown.DropdownListEntries(dropdown.Range.Text).Value
        
        Case "T1001"
            cell.Range.Text = "14C33242"
        Case "T2001"
            cell.Range.Text = "14C33342"
        Case "T3001"
            cell.Range.Text = "14C43342"
        Case "T4001"
            cell.Range.Text = "14C33342"
        Case "T5001"
            cell.Range.Text = "12C33342"
        Case "T6001"
            cell.Range.Text = "14C33342"
        Case "T7001"
            cell.Range.Text = "14C33342"

    End Select
End Sub
```

I get an [error 13 type mismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe7iy.png)

the name of the cell, the plain text title, and the dropdown are correct.
i try to chang the values to number and retried with a numbering system, it gives me the same error, regardless of what i do.
If i try to look at the result of the dropdown.DropdownListEntries(dropdown.Range.Text).Value, it gives me the correct answer (ex "T1001"), still it does not run...
I trouble shooted and double checked multiples times, I believe it to be an extremely simple task, i'm just too ignorant to work it out myself.
I expect the cell to upload the contant of the plain text when picking the option in the drop down menú
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When evaluating the value of a combo-box the `DropdownListEntries` are irrelevant. All you need to test is the text of the content control's range, as below.

```
Sub UpdateContent()
    Dim dropdown As ContentControl
    Dim cell As ContentControl
    
    Set dropdown = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("KörperTypen").Item(1)
    Set cell = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Klassifizierungen").Item(1)
    
    
    Select Case dropdown.Range.Text
        
        Case "T1001"
            cell.Range.Text = "14C33242"
        Case "T2001"
            cell.Range.Text = "14C33342"
        Case "T3001"
            cell.Range.Text = "14C43342"
        Case "T4001"
            cell.Range.Text = "14C33342"
        Case "T5001"
            cell.Range.Text = "12C33342"
        Case "T6001"
            cell.Range.Text = "14C33342"
        Case "T7001"
            cell.Range.Text = "14C33342"

    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Great thanks!
I had figured out it was something like this but couldn't act upon it.
It worked immediately and with 0 problems.
Now I have to figure out how to make the macro run automatically when selecting one of the options of the dropdown, but I guess that's another problem :-P
Thanks again!